# "Fade In" effect for text when they appear after \pause

Tags: beamer, animations, pause, transition

How can I make a "fade in" effect of text after being paused in Beamer. For example

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    
    \begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item text 1 with fade in effect \pause
        \item text2 with fade in effect
        \end{itemize}
      \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

I want the first item and second item to appear with fade in effect, rather than the default of suddenly visible.

Comment: always make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i have edited my post.

Comment: but you haven't tested your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer test where? U mean I have to post image? That code is very basic. I dont know how to make Fade In effect.

Comment: your code errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, just edited again

Comment: add `\transfade`. Be aware that such transitions typically only work if you use the PDF in full screen mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer writing once applies for all `\pause`, how to turn it on and then off in one slide??

Comment: the beamer documentation contains a long section about these effect.